# Storing values of arbitrary type

Tags: clojure, datomic

I want to store arbitrary key value pairs. For example,

```
{:foo "bar" ; string
 :n 12 ; long
 :p 1.2 ; float
}
```

In datomic, I'd like to store it as something like:

```
[{:kv/key "foo"
  :kv/value "bar"}
 {:kv/key "n"
  :kv/value 12}
 {:kv/key "p"
  :kv/value 1.2}]
```

The problem is `:kv/value` can only have one type in datomic. A solution is to to split `:kv/value` into `:kv/value-string`, `:kv/value-long`, `:kv/value-float`, etc. It comes with its own issues like making sure only one value attribute is used at a time. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you could give more details on your specific use-case it might be easier to figure out the best answer. At this point it is a bit of a mystery why you may want to have an attribute that can sometimes be a string, sometimes an int, etc.

From what you've said so far, your only real answer it to have different attributes like `value-string` etc. This is like in a SQL DB you have only 1 type per table column and would need different columns to store a string, integer, etc.

As your problem shows, any tool (such as a DB) is designed with certain assumptions. In this case the DB assumes that each "column" (attribute in Datomic) is always of the same type. The DB also assumes that you will (usually) want to have data in all columns/attrs for each record/entity.

In your problem you are contradicting both of these assumptions. While you can still use the DB to store information, you will have to write custom functions to ensure only 1 attribute (value-string, value-int, etc) is in use at one time. You probably want custom insertion functions like "insert-str-val", "insert-int-val", etc, as well as custom read functions "read-str-val" etc al.  It might be also a good idea to have a validation function that could accept any record/entity and verify that exactly one-and-only-one "type" was in use at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a key-value store with heterogenous values by making `:kv/key` a `:db.unique/identity` attribute, and by making `:kv/value` either bytes-typed or string-typed and encoding the values in the format you like (e.g fressian / nippy for `:db.types/bytes`, edn / json for `:db.types/string`). I advise that you set `:db/index` to `false` for `:kv/value` in this case.

Notes:

1. you will have limited query power, as the values will not be indexed and will need to be de-serialized for each query.
2. If you want to run transaction functions which read or write the values (e.g for data migrations), you should make your encoding / decoding library available to the Transactor as well.
3. If the values are large (say, over 20kb), don't store them in Datomic; use a complementary storage service like AWS S3 and store a URL.